# Stop a Windows Service with name and filtered by PID in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How can I stop a service using Powershell with filtering of `PID`? For example I have bunch of services service called `ArcSOC.exe` and I want to ONLY stop the one which has `PID` of `108460`.

[image]

```
Stop-Service -Name "ArcSOC.exe" -Force
```

Comment: If it's OK to _forcefully terminate_ your service, then `Stop-Process` may be an option. Please clarify if you need the service to _shut down in an orderly fashion_, which is what `Stop-Service` does.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the taskkill command

```
taskkill /F /PID 108460
```

The -F flag is to force it to stop and the /PID is to stop the process by PID instead of by name

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to stop a specific instance of a process, instead of Stop-Serivce you can use:

```
Stop-Process -Id 108460 -Force
```

If you want to return the process you stopped, you can append **-PassThru** to the command and feed the result into a variable:

```
$deadProcess = Stop-Process -Id 108460 -Force -PassThru
```

When using **Stop-Process** you should note, that the process does not stop in an orderly fashion like when using **Stop-Service**. There is also the danger of incidentally killing other processes and services, that depend on you process you stopped.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to stop the process :

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "ArcSOC.exe" -and $_.Id -eq 108460 } | Stop-Process -Force
```

By the way, I've used a "name -eq", in which case it's useless, the id is sufficient, but it's always cleaner (it can avoid deleting an unwanted service by mistyping the id, for example).

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for feedback, i used arcsoc.exe as name because it was simpler as an example, he can put what he wants

Comment: Thanks for updating, but - as you note - matching by `.Id` is sufficient, and your command can be simplified to `Stop-Process -Id 108460 -Force`, which is 2Who's answer.

Comment: if I added a comment after the two already present were only to show a more "complete" version if he ever needs one. 
It can be a waste of time, but in a big script, it can also make it more readable for any collaborator. 
At least, that's how I learned.